# get default FontFamily

Tags: xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms

In `Xamarin.Forms` I change `FontFamily` from `myButton`. Now I want to set default `FontFamily` to it. Now I use `myButton.FontFamily = (new Button()).FontFamily`. Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can reset the value to it's Default:

```cs
myButton.ClearValue(Button.FontFamilyProperty);
```